# Printing 2D Array using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main(){
 int a[2][2]={1, 2, 3, 4};
 int a[2][2]={1, 2, 3, 4};
 display(a, 2, 2);
 show(a, 2, 2);}
}

display(int *k, int r, int c){
int i, j, *z;
 for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
   z = k + i;
   printf("Display\n");
      for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
          printf("%d", *(z + j));
       }
  }
}

show(int *q, int ro, int co){
int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < ro; i++){
     printf("\n");
     for(j = 0; j < co; j++){
       printf("%d", *(q + i*co + j));
     }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Display
12
23
Show
12
34
```

Why `Display()` is not showing 1223 while `show()` gives 1234? Both uses the same logic to display the 2d array. Can any one help please?

Comment: first, put our code in a readable format!

Comment: Please invest the small amount of time required to figure out how to indent your code properly. Nobody here wants to read that mess.

Comment: If you're too lazy, at least run `indent -kr` on your file before copypasting it...

Answer (score 1):

In `display` you are using two counters, `i` for rows and `j` for columns. Since the array is laid out sequentially in memory you need to increase `i` by the size of a column, i.e. c, each time you want to move from one row to the next. So, you should add `i*c` to k, not `i`.

The complete function:

```
display(int *k,int r,int c){
int i,j,*z;
 for(i=0;i<r;i++){
   z=k+i*c;
   printf("Display\n");
      for(j=0;j<c;j++){
          printf("%d",*(z+j));
       }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access 2D array using pointers:

```
#define R 2
#define C 2
...
int A[R][C]={1, 2, 3, 4};
for(i=0;i<R;i++)  
  for(j=0;j<C;j++)
    printf("%d ",*(*(A+i)+j));
...
```